# Sorting an array based on 2 other arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have 3 integer arrays, each of size 20:

`int[] Sec = new int[20];`

`int[] Num = new int[20];`

`int[] Tim = new int[20];`

I'm trying to sort `Num` by descending values in `Sec`, then by ascending values in `Tim`.

Typically, values in `Sec` will have duplicates and values in `Tim` won't.

Anybody got any ideas, I've been stuck for 2 days now.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to understand this one-liner-solution then: *var result = Enumerable.Range(0,20).OrderByDescending(i=> Sec[i]).ThenBy(i=>Tim[i]).Select(i=>Num[i]).ToArray();*

Comment: Seems like someone allegedly stuck for two days would have some code to share

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, thank you so much eocron!

Comment: Stuck for 2 days, eocron responed 3 mins after post. 2 days = 960 minutes (of 8 hr days). 960/3 = 320 -> nice job @eocron, you are officially a 320x dev.

Comment: Need some sleep, actually >_<

Comment: or the OP is a .003125 dev

Comment: Technically, the OP never solved the problem that eocron solved in 3 minutes, so eocron is infinitely better. Mathematically speaking.